# Pluck unique values from an ActiveRecord has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following association: `Artist has_many Songs`. Hence, I can get an artist's songs by doing:

```
artist.songs
```

However, I would like to get only the songs' genre:

```
artist.songs.pluck(:genre)
```

But, this genre may appear multiple times in the results; I would only like to get unique genre values. Unfortunately, `pluck` isn't of any help here, since it returns an array, and calling `uniq` on it won't tweak the ActiveRecord query, but the plain `Array#uniq`.

I can do it like this:

```
artist.songs.select(:genre).uniq.pluck(:genre)
```

but I feel there must be a better way.

P.S.: From some minimal benchmarks, however, `pluck + Array#uniq` seems a bit faster than `select + uniq + pluck`.

Comment: Are you sure that `uniq` does not tweak the ActiveRecord query?

Answer (score 6):

If using the artist's `songs` association, you can `select distinct` on `genre`, then map over the results to just return the strings:

```
artist.songs.select('distinct genre').map(&:genre)
# or...
artist.songs.select(:genre).uniq.map(&:genre) # uniq or distinct work
```

resulting query:

`(0.2ms) SELECT distinct genre FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."artist_id" = ?  [["artist_id", 1]]`

You could also use uniq if calling on the Song model directly while narrowing to the artist:

`Song.where(artist: artist).uniq.pluck(:genre)`

resulting query:

`(0.2ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "songs"."genre" FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."artist_id" = 1`

Both are equally and efficient and do the uniqueness operation in SQL and not in Ruby.

Comment: Esentially you're suggesting using `select + uniq + Array#map` instead of `select + uniq + pluck`. They're pretty much the same; for a large number of associated records I guess `pluck` does better than `Array#map`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of Rails 5, [`Relation#uniq` is deprecated; you should use `Relation#distinct` instead](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/adfab2dcf4003ca564d78d4425566dd2d9cd8b4f).

I recently came across this same issue myself. Ideally, I would like the following code to work - but it does not generate SQL to fetch distinct values only:

```
artist.songs.distinct.pluck(:genre)
```

As a workaround however, you can instead do:

```
Song.where(artist: artist).distinct.pluck(:genre)
```

This will generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "songs"."genre" FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."artist_id" = 123
```

For convenience, you could also consider adding this as a model method such as:

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  def genres
    Song.where(artist: self).distinct.pluck(:genre)
  end
end
```

This achieves optimal performance, as the query is entirely in SQL - there are no ruby operations such as `Array#map` or `Array#uniq` being used.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.uniq.pluck(:genre)
```

this generates SQl query `SELECT DISTINCT` rather than querying .uniq to an array again.

Comment: I've mentioned that I am using this on an association, which does not work the same as directly on the model.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this.

```
artist.songs.pluck('DISTINCT genre')
```

I am still in search of better way. I feel this is cleaner than `select(:col).uniq.pluck(:col)`

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to the other answers. If you want to select unique rows based on a particular column, you can also use

`artist.pluck('distinct on (col1) col1, col2, col3')`

which is basically

`select distinct on (col1) col1, col2, col3 from artist`

you can also do this with select

`artist.select('distinct on (col1) col1, col2, col3')`

pluck gives array of values, where as select gives array of records.